# How to get selected value from f.select tag in controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

How can i get value from f.select tag in my controller. Here is my erb code

```
<td>
  <%= f.text_field :startdate , :id => "from", :placeholder => "Start Date"%>   
</td>    
<td>           
<%= f.select :repetitive_task, options_for_select(["Every Day","Every Week", "Every Month"]), {:prompt => 'None'}, {:id => "select1"} %>
</td>
```

And Here is my controller --

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if params[:repetitive_task] == "Every Day" 
     @micropost.targetdate = params[:startdate]
  elsif params[:repetitive_task] == "Every Week" 
     @micropost.targetdate = params[:startdate] + 7
  elsif params[:repetitive_task] == "Every Month"
     @micropost.targetdate = params[:startdate] + 30 
  else
  end      
  if @micropost.save 
    flash[:success] = "Task created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else             
   render 'static_pages/index'
end
```

Value does not fetch when i click on submit button. Please help

Comment: You're doing it wrong. you startdate will be nested in micropost hash. so you need to fetch it using params[:micropost][:startdate].

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= f.select :repetitive_task,options_for_select(["Every Day","Every Week", "Every Month"], params[:micropost][:repetitive_task])
, {:prompt => 'None'}, {:id => "select1"} %>
```

Pass **second** parameter in **options_for_select** to show selected value.

Also use params[:micropost][:repetitive_task] instead of using params[:repetitive_task] in controller.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. params[:micropost][:repetitive_task] working

Answer (score 2):

if you are using form_for helper (for example form_for :micropost) you should have all values in params[:micropost]. In your case you should have :repetitive_task in

```
params[:micropost][:repetitive_task]
```